# Why the deduced return type of a method with a ExpandoObject parameter is always dynamic?

Tags: c#, expandoobject

As code snippet below, why the deduced type of `list` is dynamic in VS2017? Thus, this code will produce compile error. And I notice that if I change the `dynamic` keyword to `var`, then everything is OK.

How to fix it if I want to keep using `dynamic` keyword?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        var list = GetList(d); // ===> vs deduced list as dynamic
        var r = list.Select(x => x.Replace("a", "_"));
        var slist = new List<string>();
        var sr = slist.Select(x => x.Replace("a", "_"));
        Console.WriteLine(r.Count());
    }

    static List<string> GetList(ExpandoObject obj)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "abc", "def" };
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked for dynamic. Any method calls involving it aren't going to have name resolution performed on them until runtime. That's precisely what you asked for. It can't know what the method *it hasn't picked yet* is going to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations involving an argument declared as `dynamic` are inferred to return dynamics themselves. From the [c# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

> The result of most dynamic operations is itself dynamic.  Operations in which the result is not dynamic include: (1) Conversions from dynamic to another type (2) Constructor calls that include arguments of type dynamic.

If you want to convert back to a non-dynamic type, just declare the variable the way you want it. This works:

```
List<string> list = GetList(d);
```

...and will allow the rest of your code to compile.